# Return an allocated array of strings from subroutine in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, string, fortran, gfortran, subroutine

I need to return an an array of strings from a subroutine in fortran, the length of which is supposed to be determined at runtime. The solution I have found, which works with intel fortran, crashes with gfortran however.

### Example Code

The following code seems to work with Intel Fortran (15.0.3), but fails with a segmentation fault with gfortran 5.3.0:

```
program stringtest   ! filename:str2.f08
  implicit none
  integer n
  character(len=:), allocatable :: y(:)

  write(*,*) 'mkchars...'
  call mkchars(y)
  write(*,*) 'mkchars... Done.'
  write(*,'(5("|",A,"|"))') y

contains 

  subroutine mkchars(oc)
    character(len=:), allocatable, intent(out) :: oc(:)
    allocate(character(len=8) :: oc(5))
    write(*,*) 'shape  ', shape(oc)
    write(*,*) 'length ', (len(oc(n)), n=1,5)
    write(*,*) 'storage', storage_size(oc)
    oc(1) = "Hello"
    oc(2) = "World" ! <-------------------- crashes here with gfortran
    oc(3) = "how"
    oc(4) = "are"
    oc(5) = "you?"
  end subroutine mkchars

end program stringtest
```

#### IFort output

With Intel Fortran 15.0.3, this produces

```
 mkchars...
 shape             5
 length            8           8           8           8           8
 storage          64
 mkchars... Done.
|Hello   ||World   ||how     ||are     ||you?    |
```

#### GFortran: Executable Crashes upon assignment to OC(2)

With gfortran, however, I get a segmentation fault when assigning to `OC(2)`, even though the shape of the array and the length of each entry are reported as expected:

```
C:\tmp>gdb -batch -ex run -ex bt a.exe
[New Thread 12024.0x38e4]
 mkchars...
 shape             5
 length            8           8           8           8           8
 storage          64

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401840 in mkchars (oc=<incomplete type>, _oc=_oc@entry=0x61fdbc) at c:/tmp/str2.f08:20
20          oc(2) = "World"
#0  0x0000000000401840 in mkchars (oc=<incomplete type>, _oc=_oc@entry=0x61fdbc) at c:/tmp/str2.f08:20
#1  0x00000000004019a0 in stringtest () at c:/tmp/str2.f08:9
#2  0x0000000000401a84 in main (argc=1, argv=0x6f5890) at c:/tmp/str2.f08:9
#3  0x00000000004013e8 in __tmainCRTStartup ()
#4  0x000000000040151b in mainCRTStartup ()
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a possible compiler bug?

Is there some other method of returning allocated string-arrays from subroutines that works in gfortran?

For the actual use-case at hand, I can fall back to using an oversized fixed-size array (roughly 100KB instead of <1KB) and ignoring the unused parts. I would however prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: gfortran-7.1 gives the same output as ifort-15 above, so possibly a bug of gfortran-5.3...?

Comment: With an online compiler [here](https://tio.run/##hVJBTsMwELznFUsusSu3UoFIKKJCSBz4AcfKdZfEIrGjtdMqiL8HO21KUYvIwVqPZ2dmHb9b8iTNvHw/FMPQki1JNuA8aVN6dD4B6ByCdnZ9ZK3R7ARYU/cFKNu0ukZa75CctiawddPWWmkPxhqMe@OxRIJ4pipJUnkkVqNZFVyArGurpJebGqEooGcFTwKxDfYeZgLSzoUgkIoLKzYS96Q9spmYcciaj6jvFotFFr2CNBwh1vM/ufASco4d03nGcpZ@peJZhJXzjEOfJMoaL7VxEF1dtyHbeW3w5GBVtPhnRDHehvEsNPM4r1Vx4Nh3ZCH7LfAw0XJ@4J0P4SrZIkAmYKxOGc45QaT0VeREvUBhhodQZrUU@RVFb0mWGBUP1drpzx/h0L3ksIL0FUPcdMJuR@zNUr1N4QYe51c@UCRdhQ4qJIS9DpmmZzfJ3I0yld2fhO9HRBKekHxEets9RQjN9sq/SJKIXz7lYfgG)

Comment: Very likely a bug that has been fixed in more recent versions.

Comment: Is there some workaround available? I don't want to introduce a depency on a newer compiler version for now, so an alternative, if possible, would be helpful.

Comment: Don't use allocatable arrays if character strings...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Fortran string class a while back for my code "MOONS". The way I wrote the string class was to first wrap a single character in a derived type (char), and then make an outer class (string) that uses an allocatable of the char type. This way, I avoid writing an allocatable of characters and, instead, write an allocatable of derived types.

When I was first developing this class, I first tried using the same sort of approach that you have shown, but I experienced compilation/runtime errors. This string class works for gfortran 4.9.2. I have tested it with other versions, but I don't remember which ones specifically.

Here's the github, which will have the most updated string class version

https://github.com/charliekawczynski/MOONS

The current directory for the string class is

https://github.com/charliekawczynski/MOONS/blob/master/code/pre_generated/string.f90

But I can't guarantee that won't change in the future. I'll include the current version here:

```
  module string_mod
  implicit none
  ! Implimentation:

  ! program test_string
  ! use string_mod
  ! implicit none
  ! type(string) :: s
  ! call init(s,'This is');            write(*,*) 'string = ',str(s)
  ! call append(s,' a variable');      write(*,*) 'string = ',str(s)
  ! call append(s,' sized string!');   write(*,*) 'string = ',str(s)
  ! call compress(s);                  write(*,*) 'string, no spaces = ',str(s)
  ! call delete(s)
  ! end program

  private

  character(len=4),parameter :: dot_dat = '.dat'

  public :: string
  public :: init,delete,display,print,export,import ! Essentials

  public :: write_formatted
  public :: string_allocated
  public :: get_str,str ! str does not require length
  public :: len,match,match_index
  public :: compress,append,prepend
  public :: get_char,set_char
  public :: remove_element
  public :: identical

  public :: set_IO_dir
  public :: make_IO_dir
  public :: export_structured
  public :: import_structured
  public :: export_primitives
  public :: import_primitives

  interface init;                 module procedure init_size;                      end interface
  interface init;                 module procedure init_string;                    end interface
  interface init;                 module procedure init_copy;                      end interface
  interface delete;               module procedure delete_string;                  end interface
  interface display;              module procedure display_string;                 end interface
  interface print;                module procedure print_string;                   end interface
  interface export;               module procedure export_string;                  end interface
  interface import;               module procedure import_string;                  end interface

  interface write_formatted;      module procedure write_formatted_string;         end interface
  interface string_allocated;     module procedure string_allocated_string;        end interface

  interface append;               module procedure app_string_char;                end interface
  interface append;               module procedure app_string_string;              end interface
  interface prepend;              module procedure prep_string_char;               end interface
  interface prepend;              module procedure prep_string_string;             end interface
  interface compress;             module procedure compress_string;                end interface
  interface len;                  module procedure str_len_string;                 end interface
  interface str;                  module procedure get_str_short;                  end interface
  interface get_str;              module procedure get_str_string;                 end interface
  interface match;                module procedure substring_in_string;            end interface
  interface match_index;          module procedure index_substring_in_string;      end interface
  interface get_char;             module procedure get_char_string;                end interface
  interface set_char;             module procedure set_char_string;                end interface
  interface remove_element;       module procedure remove_element_string;          end interface
  interface identical;            module procedure identical_string_string;        end interface
  interface identical;            module procedure identical_string_char;          end interface

  interface insist_allocated;     module procedure insist_allocated_string;        end interface

  ! Copied from generated code:

  interface set_IO_dir;           module procedure set_IO_dir_string;              end interface
  interface make_IO_dir;          module procedure make_IO_dir_string;             end interface
  interface export_structured;    module procedure export_structured_D_string;     end interface
  interface import_structured;    module procedure import_structured_D_string;     end interface
  interface export_primitives;    module procedure export_primitives_string;       end interface
  interface import_primitives;    module procedure import_primitives_string;       end interface
  interface suppress_warnings;    module procedure suppress_warnings_string;       end interface

  type char
    private
    character(len=1) :: c
  end type

  type string
    private
    type(char),dimension(:),allocatable :: s ! string
    integer :: n = 0                         ! string length
  end type

  contains

  subroutine init_size(st,n)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: st
    integer,intent(in) :: n
    if (n.lt.1) stop 'Error: string must be of size > 1 in string.f90'
    call delete(st)
    allocate(st%s(n))
    st%n = n
  end subroutine

  subroutine init_string(st,s)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: st
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: s
    integer :: i
    call init(st,len(s))
    do i=1,st%n
      call init_char(st%s(i),s(i:i))
    enddo
  end subroutine

  subroutine init_copy(a,b)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: a
    type(string),intent(in) :: b
    integer :: i
    call delete(a)
    ! call insist_allocated(b,'init_copy')
    if ((b%n.gt.0).and.(string_allocated(b))) then
      call init(a,b%n)
      do i=1,b%n
      call init_copy_char(a%s(i),b%s(i))
      enddo
      a%n = b%n
    endif
  end subroutine

  subroutine delete_string(st)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: st
    if (allocated(st%s)) deallocate(st%s)
    st%n = 0
  end subroutine

  subroutine display_string(st,un)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: st
    integer,intent(in) :: un
    call export(st,un)
  end subroutine

  subroutine print_string(st)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: st
    call display(st,6)
    write(6,*) ''
  end subroutine

  subroutine export_string(st,un)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: st
    integer,intent(in) :: un
    ! call insist_allocated(st,'export_string')
    if (string_allocated(st)) then
      write(un,*) str(st)
    else
      write(un,*) 'string not allocated'
    endif
  end subroutine

  subroutine import_string(s,un)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: s
    integer,intent(in) :: un
    character(len=1) :: c
    logical :: first_iteration,continue_loop
    integer :: ReadCode
    ReadCode = 0; continue_loop = .true.
    call delete(s); first_iteration = .true.
    do while (continue_loop)
      if (ReadCode.eq.0) then
        read(un,'(A)',advance='no',iostat=ReadCode) c
        if (first_iteration) then; call init(s,c); else; call append(s,c); endif
      else; continue_loop = .false.; exit
      endif; first_iteration = .false.
    enddo
    if (s%s(s%n)%c.eq.' ') call remove_element(s,s%n)
    if (s%s(1)%c.eq.' ') call remove_element(s,1)
  end subroutine

  subroutine write_formatted_string(s,un)
    implicit none
    integer,intent(in) :: un
    type(string),intent(in) :: s
    write(un,'('//int2str(len(s))//'A)') str(s)
  end subroutine

  function int2Str(i) result(s)
    implicit none
    integer,intent(in) :: i
    character(len=15) :: s
    write(s,'(I15.15)') i
    s = trim(adjustl(s))
  end function

  ! **********************************************************
  ! **********************************************************
  ! **********************************************************

  subroutine app_string_char(st,s)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: st
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: s
    type(string) :: temp
    integer :: i,n
    n = len(s)
    call init(temp,st)
    call init(st,temp%n+n)
    do i=1,temp%n
      call init_copy_char(st%s(i),temp%s(i))
    enddo
    do i=1,n
      call init_char(st%s(temp%n+i),s(i:i))
    enddo
    call delete(temp)
  end subroutine

  subroutine app_string_string(a,b)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: a
    type(string),intent(in) :: b
    call append(a,str(b))
  end subroutine

  subroutine prep_string_char(a,b)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: a
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: b
    type(string) :: temp
    call init(temp,b)
    call append(temp,a)
    call init(a,temp)
    call delete(temp)
  end subroutine

  subroutine prep_string_string(a,b)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: a
    type(string),intent(in) :: b
    call prepend(a,str(b))
  end subroutine

  subroutine compress_string(st)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: st
    type(string) :: temp
    integer :: i,n_spaces,k
    if (st%n.lt.1) stop 'Error: input string must be > 1 in string.f90'
    n_spaces = 0
    do i=1,st%n
      if (st%s(i)%c.eq.' ') n_spaces = n_spaces + 1
    enddo
    if (n_spaces.ne.0) then
      if (st%n-n_spaces.lt.1) stop 'Error: only spaces in string in compress_string in string.f90'
      call init(temp,st%n-n_spaces)
      k = 0
      do i=1,st%n
        if (st%s(i)%c.ne.' ') then
          temp%s(i-k)%c = st%s(i)%c
        else; k = k+1
        endif
      enddo
      call init(st,temp)
      call delete(temp)
    endif
  end subroutine

  subroutine remove_element_string(st,i)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: st
    integer,intent(in) :: i
    type(string) :: temp
    integer :: j,k
    if (st%n.lt.1) stop 'Error: input string must be > 1 in remove_element_string in string.f90'
    if ((i.lt.1).or.(i.gt.st%n)) stop 'Error: element out of bounds in remove_element_string in string.f90'
    k = 0
    call init(temp,st%n-1)
    do j=1,st%n
      if (i.ne.j) then
        temp%s(j-k)%c = st%s(j)%c
      else; k = 1
      endif
    enddo
    call init(st,temp)
    call delete(temp)
  end subroutine

  function identical_string_string(A,B) result(L)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: A,B
    logical :: L
    integer :: i
    call insist_allocated(A,'A identical_string_string')
    call insist_allocated(B,'B identical_string_string')
    L = .false.
    if (A%n.eq.B%n) then
      L = .true.
      do i=1,A%n
        if (A%s(i)%c.ne.B%s(i)%c) L = .false.
      enddo
    endif
  end function

  function identical_string_char(A,B) result(L)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: A
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: B
    type(string) :: temp
    logical :: L
    call insist_allocated(A,'A identical_string_string')
    call init(temp,B)
    L = identical(A,temp)
    call delete(temp)
  end function

  function get_char_string(st,i) result(c)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: st
    integer,intent(in) :: i
    character(len=1) :: c
    c = st%s(i)%c
  end function

  subroutine set_char_string(st,c,i)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(inout) :: st
    integer,intent(in) :: i
    character(len=1),intent(in) :: c
    st%s(i)%c = c
  end subroutine

  function get_str_short(st) result(str)
    type(string),intent(in) :: st
    character(len=st%n) :: str
    str = get_str_string(st,st%n)
  end function

  pure function str_len_string(s) result(n)
    type(string),intent(in) :: s
    integer :: n
    n = s%n
  end function

  function get_str_string(st,n) result(str)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: st
    integer,intent(in) :: n
    character(len=n) :: str
    integer :: i
    call insist_allocated(st,'get_str_string')
    if (st%n.lt.1) stop 'Error: st%n.lt.0 in get_str_string in string.f90'
    if (n.lt.1) stop 'Error: n.lt.1 in get_str_string in string.f90'
    do i=1,st%n
      str(i:i) = st%s(i)%c
    enddo
  end function

  function substring_in_string(str,substr) result(L)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: str
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: substr
    logical :: L,cond
    integer :: i,j,s
    L = .false.
    s = len(substr)
    if (s.lt.1) stop 'Error: len(substr) must be > 1 in substring_in_string in string.f90'
    do i=1,len(str)-s
      cond = all((/(str%s(i+j-1:i+j-1)%c .eq. substr(j:j),j=1,s)/))
      if (cond) then
        L = .true.
        exit
      endif
    enddo
  end function

  function index_substring_in_string(str,substr) result(index)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: str
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: substr
    logical :: cond
    integer :: index,i,j,s
    s = len(substr)
    cond = .false.
    index = 1
    if (s.lt.1) stop 'Error: len(substr) must be > 1 in index_substring_in_string in string.f90'
    do i=1,len(str)-s
      cond = all((/(str%s(i+j-1:i+j-1)%c .eq. substr(j:j),j=1,s)/))
      if (cond) then
        index = i
        exit
      endif
    enddo
    if (.not.cond) stop 'Error: substring not found in index_substring_in_string in string.f90'
  end function

  subroutine init_char(CH,c)
    implicit none
    type(char),intent(inout) :: CH
    character(len=1),intent(in) :: c
    CH%c = c
  end subroutine

  subroutine init_copy_char(a,b)
    implicit none
    type(char),intent(inout) :: a
    type(char),intent(in) :: b
    a%c = b%c
  end subroutine

  function string_allocated_string(st) result(L)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: st
    logical :: L
    L = allocated(st%s)
  end function

  function valid_length(st) result(L)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: st
    logical :: L
    L = st%n.gt.0
  end function

  ! function valid_string(st) result(L)
  !   implicit none
  !   type(string),intent(in) :: st
  !   logical :: L
  !   L = string_allocated(st).and.valid_length(st)
  ! end function

  subroutine insist_allocated_string(st,s)
    implicit none
    type(string),intent(in) :: st
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: s
    if (.not.string_allocated(st)) then
      write(*,*) 'Error: string must be allocated in '//s//' in string.f90'
      stop 'Done'
    elseif (.not.valid_length(st)) then
      write(*,*) 'Error: string must have a valid length in '//s//' in string.f90'
      stop 'Done'
    endif
  end subroutine

  ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ! ----------------------------- COPIED FROM IO TOOLS -----------------------------
  ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function open_to_read(dir,name) result(un)
    implicit none
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: dir,name
    integer :: un
    type(string) :: s
    call init(s,dir//name//dot_dat)
    un = new_unit()
    open(un,file=str(s),status = 'old',action = 'read')
    call delete(s)
  end function

  function new_and_open(dir,name) result(un)
    implicit none
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: dir,name
    integer :: un
    type(string) :: s
    call init(s,dir//name//dot_dat)
    un = new_unit()
    call attempt_to_open_to_write(un,s,dir,name)
    call delete(s)
  end function

  function new_unit() result(nu)
    implicit none
    integer,parameter :: lun_min=10,lun_max=1000
    integer :: lun,nu
    nu=-1
    do lun=lun_min,lun_max
      if (.not.unit_open(lun)) then; nu=lun; exit; endif
    enddo
  end function

  subroutine attempt_to_open_to_write(un,s,dir,name)
    implicit none
    integer,intent(in) :: un
    type(string),intent(in) :: s
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: dir,name
    integer :: n,i
    logical :: failed
    failed = .true.
    do n=1,100000
      open(un,file=str(s),pad='YES',action='readwrite',iostat=i)
      if (i.eq.0) then; failed = .false.; exit; endif
    enddo
    if (failed) then
      write(*,*) 'Error: tried to open file but failed!!'
      write(*,*) 'File = ',str(s)
      write(*,*) 'dir = ',dir
      write(*,*) 'name = ',name
      stop 'Done in attempt_to_open_to_write in IO_tools.f90'
    endif
  end subroutine

  function unit_open(un) result(op)
    implicit none
    integer,intent(in) :: un
    logical :: op
    inquire(unit=un,opened=op)
  end function

  ! subroutine make_dir(d)
  !   implicit none
  !   character(len=*),intent(in) :: d
  !   logical :: ex
  !   inquire (file=d, EXIST=ex)
  !   if (.not.ex) then
  !     call system('mkdir ' // d )
  !     write(*,*) 'Directory ' // d // ' created.'
  !   else
  !     write(*,*) 'Directory ' // d // ' already exists.'
  !   endif
  ! end subroutine

  subroutine make_dir_quiet(d)
    implicit none
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: d
    logical :: ex
    inquire (file=d, EXIST=ex)
    if (.not.ex) call system('mkdir ' // d )
  end subroutine

  ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ! -------------------------- COPIED FROM GENERATED CODE --------------------------
  ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   subroutine set_IO_dir_string(this,dir)
     implicit none
     type(string),intent(inout) :: this
     character(len=*),intent(in) :: dir
     call suppress_warnings(this)
     if (.false.) then
       write(*,*) dir
     endif
   end subroutine

   subroutine make_IO_dir_string(this,dir)
     implicit none
     type(string),intent(inout) :: this
     character(len=*),intent(in) :: dir
     call suppress_warnings(this)
     call make_dir_quiet(dir)
   end subroutine

   subroutine export_structured_D_string(this,dir)
     implicit none
     type(string),intent(in) :: this
     character(len=*),intent(in) :: dir
     integer :: un
     un = new_and_open(dir,'primitives')
     call export(this,un)
     close(un)
   end subroutine

   subroutine import_structured_D_string(this,dir)
     implicit none
     type(string),intent(inout) :: this
     character(len=*),intent(in) :: dir
     integer :: un
     un = open_to_read(dir,'primitives')
     call import(this,un)
     close(un)
   end subroutine

   subroutine export_primitives_string(this,un)
     implicit none
     type(string),intent(in) :: this
     integer,intent(in) :: un
     call export(this,un)
   end subroutine

   subroutine import_primitives_string(this,un)
     implicit none
     type(string),intent(inout) :: this
     integer,intent(in) :: un
     call import(this,un)
   end subroutine

   subroutine suppress_warnings_string(this)
     implicit none
     type(string),intent(in) :: this
     if (.false.) then
       call print(this)
     endif
   end subroutine

  end module
```

Comment: Given that there is so much code here, can you please explain how this answers the question?  In particular, note that the consensus is that the problem was a result of a compiler bug.